# Transforming CRS for globcover data using R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, vector

I have two set of data:

1. raster land cover from [Globcover]:(http://www.fao.org/land-water/land/land-governance/land-resources-planning-toolbox/category/details/en/c/1036356/)
2. A set of point shapefiles of health facilities in Africa.[Google drive]:(https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Oi9Bd_T_W82DXZjN7XUCoAyvM6kCVkYQ?usp=sharing)

I have problems with ensuring that they are aligned after transforming their CRS from geographic coordinate system to projected coordinate system.

Both files has CRS of WGS84. I tried to plot them both in WGS84 and they are aligned perfectly, as shown below.

```
crs(landcover)

CRS arguments:
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

crs(healthfac_point)

CRS arguments:
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

[image]

However, when I convert both the CRS of the globcover data and point shapefiles into epsg:32735, they no longer line up.

```
healthfac_point_projected <- spTransform(healthfac_point, CRS("+init=epsg:32735"))

crs(healthfac_point_projected)

CRS arguments:
+init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

projection(landcover) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32735")

crs(landcover)
CRS arguments:
+init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

extent(healthfac_point_projected)

class       : Extent 
xmin        : -5832574 
xmax        : 4548844 
ymin        : 6136173 
ymax        : 13175174 

extent(landcover)

class       : Extent 
xmin        : -180.0014 
xmax        : 179.9986 
ymin        : -64.99861 
ymax        : 90.00139
```

I also tried this.

```
healthfac_point_projected <- spTransform(healthfac_point, CRS("+init=epsg:32735"))

crs(healthfac_point_projected)

CRS arguments:
+init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

landcover_proj <- projectRaster(landcover, proj4string(healthfac_point_projected))

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘res’ for signature ‘"character"’
In addition: Warning message:
In min(dim(to)[1:2]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Ultimately I would like to create buffers around these point shapefiles and find out the % land cover in each buffer. However, as their extent are different despite transforming their CRS, I cannot do that.

Can you point out what's wrong with the way I have transformed the CRS of both files?

Answer (score 2):

It's this bit, is wrong it assigns the crs doesn't *apply it by transforming the data*:

```
projection(landcover) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32735")
```

you're expected to transform the raster i.e.

```
new <- raster(healthfac_point_projected)
res(new) <- c(150000, 150000) ## change resolution to suit, this is metres (the width,height of each cell)
landcoverutm <- projectRaster(landcover, new)
```

Untested. UTM is not a great choice and officially *bad* for such a wide set of longitudes, for this kind of region I'd probably use LambertAzimuthalEqualArea (or a Conic, ...,  but this is not that question). Try

```
"+proj=laea +lon_0=40 +lat_0=-10 +datum=WGS84"
```

With newer raster/rgdal/sp/etc you'll want to drop the '+ellps' arg which will cause warnings and be unused.